# Typescript Chain Async Call

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, call, chain

I need to:

localStorage.setItem('user', user);
router.navigate(['/profile']);

The problem is that navigation may occur before storage is set.

Please tell me I don't need to route parameters, create asynchronous classes, callbacks, promisses, or timers for this to work.

Comment: localStorage is synchronous...

Comment: Could you provide a self-contained [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted into a standalone IDE?  Right now my IDE doesn't know what `user` and `router` are, nor does it seem possible that anything `router.navigate()` does can take effect before `localStorage.setItem()` does, so it would be nice to see that in action.  Without more info it's hard to advise.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may set localstorage value in useEffect hook like this:

```
 React.useEffect(()=>{ 
   setStorage()
   router.navigate(['/profile'])      
 },[])
 
 const setStorage = ()=>{  
    localStorage.setItem("user", user)  
 }
```

It'll set the value in localstorage before router.naviagte

Comment: Not quite. You need an external package and parameter exchange for the lack of a .then() -- JS was always asynchrounlously causing trouble. There has to be a better way in Typescript or, back to JS!

Comment: @AleksanderSpacca TypeScript is primarily just a static type system on top of JavaScript, and this gets erased on transpilation and therefore has no runtime effect; if you don't like how something works in JavaScript, you probably won't like how it works in TypeScript either.

Comment: Yeah, jcalz! I know how it works. I want to follow Angular's choices because to them everything is a component. People hate when I put MaintenancePlans() and PartsTTL() in a car.cs but love car.parts.sparks.ttl without 20 injectable classes that never sees a user, cart, or anything else. <app-car>parts.spark.ttl</app-car> is just expected! So I want to stick to Typescript's not thinking like JS. There has got to be a way to wait for a result before proceeding. http.get has it. I need what it uses to port a mess. Or anything.. I'm now trying to check storage before redirect.

Comment: I will wait a couple of days to see if anyone can help any further. I will not forget to mark you kuuhak-u because it helps who can use react!

Answer (score 0):

Best way I found (using callback):

```
this.save(user, response => {
  router.navigate(['/profile']);
})

save(user, callback: (error: any) => void ){
  localStorage.setItem("user", user);
  callback('done');
}
```